# Python - Rock Paper Scissors - Include Input User Name and Score Counter

Tags: python, counter, user-input

I'm trying to write a somewhat easy version of Rock Paper Scissors in Python 3 for elementary-middle school aged kids to understand easily and hopefully reproduce.

Besides the basic game, I want to incorporate the option for them to input the names for a player1 and player2, using %s so the program will print it back out. I keep getting this error in my o/p:

```
Player 1 name: me
Player 2 name: you
%s, what do you choose? Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors(3)?
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/rps/scorekeeping.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("%s, what do you choose? Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors(3)?") % player1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'**
```

I'm also trying to include the score counter which updates itself every round (player1 vs player2). Usually it resets to 0 per round for win/tie/lose.

Please help me to see where the code went wrong. Thanks!

---

```
player1 = input("Player 1 name: ")
player2 = input("Player 2 name: ")

while 1:

    player1score = 0
    player2score = 0

    print("%s, what do you choose? Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors(3)?") % player1

    choice1 = input("> ")

    print("%s, what do you choose? Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors(3)?") % player2

    choice2 = input("> ")

    if choice1 == choice2 :
        print("Its's a tie.")
    elif choice1 - choice2 == 1 or choice2 - choice1 == 2 :
        print("%s wins.") % player1
        score1 = score1 + 1
    else:
        print("%s wins.") % player2
        score2 = score2 + 1

    print("%s: %d points. %s: %d points.") % (player1, score1, player2, score2)
```

Comment: Score1 and 2 are not initialised. I think you need extra parenthesis in your print. Also, do not zero your scores in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to format the return value of your print function. Instead, to format the string you're printing, try:

```
print("%s, what do you choose? Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors(3)?" % player1)
```

for the first statement, for example. The formatting should occur inside the parenthesis.

In order to convert your input value to an integer, try:

```
choice1 = int(input("> "))
```

Currently, you're resetting the score to zero at the start of the while loop. To stop your score counters from resetting, put the

```
player1score = 0
player2score = 0
```

before the while loop.

Comment: Okay I see, fixed that now. Now I'm getting this error:                
    **Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/rps/scorekeeping.py", line 23, in <module>
        elif choice1 - choice2 == 1 or choice2 - choice1 == 2:
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'** How do I get past this?

Comment: You need to validate user input to be integer and then convert str to int. If user input is not integer - reask him.